# TCP socket programming regarding the packet and buffer size

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I know that there is no packet concept in TCP as it is a stream socket, then for example, if i have a packet of 2000 bytes, say 2000 'a', and my default buffer size is 1024, then it is supposed to send twice and received twice?

so for the send() function,

```
iResult = send(s, sendbuf, packet_size, 0);
```

for the second parameter, what should i put? a sending buffer character pointer with 1024 bytes mallocated or a packet character pointer with 2000 bytes and it will handle it for me automatically ?

and for the recv() blocking function, i should put the buffer character pointer to the second parameter or the packet one?

and for the header, my friend suggested me to add header of 4 bytes to store the packet information, eg. sequence number and size of packet, how can it be implemented ? thanks

@Giorgi, Thanks! and i also want to ask, if i dont do the partial writes handling and the send rate in the while loop is very faster (no sleep), so will there be error/lost in server side? for the recv()

```
SOCKET newsfd;
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)ReceiverSocket, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if (strcmp(protocol, "tcp") == 0 || strcmp(protocol, "TCP") == 0){
    listen(s, 1);
    newsfd = accept(s, 0, 0);
}

//*** Create Update Display Thread
std::thread th(Function_packet_transmission_display, update_interval, (char*) "recv");

//*** Receive Data//*** Set Jitter
long time_old = 0, time_new = 0, time_start = 0;
long float jitter_new = 0, jitter_old = 0;
long long temp_accubyte = 0, temp_pktnum = 0; //testing
char *recvbuf = new char[buffer_size];
long long next_seq_num = 1; int retVal;
do{

    if (strcmp(protocol, "tcp") == 0 || strcmp(protocol, "TCP") == 0){
        retVal = recv(newsfd, recvbuf, packet_size, 0);
        if ((retVal == SOCKET_ERROR) || (retVal == 0)){
            printf("\nreturn fail code:%i\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            lck.lock();
            Ended = true;
            lck.unlock();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp(protocol, "udp") == 0 || strcmp(protocol, "UDP") == 0){
        int fromlen = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        retVal = recvfrom(s, recvbuf, packet_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)ReceiverSocket, &fromlen);
    }
    //testing
    temp_accubyte += retVal;
    temp_pktnum++;//TEST
    //printf("\racc: %lld %lld    -   ", temp_accubyte, temp_pktnum);
    //if (temp_pktnum==100000)            printf("\nReach 100000\n", temp_accubyte, temp_pktnum);

    if (timer == NULL){
        timer = new ES_FlashTimer();
    }
```

Comment: @Giorgi, Thanks! and i also want to ask, if i dont do the partial writes handling and the send rate in the while loop is very faster (no sleep), so will there be error/lost in server side? for the recv()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i have a packet of 2000 bytes, say 2000 'a',

You don't. You have a *message* of 2000 bytes.

> and my default buffer size is 1024

Unlikely. It will be at least 8192, possibly many thousands of K.

> then it is supposed to send twice

At least.

> and received twice?

At least.

> for the second parameter, what should i put?

The size of the *message* you want to send: in this case, 2000.

> sending buffer character pointer with 1024 bytes mallocated

No.

> or a packet character pointer with 2000 bytes and it will handle it for me automatically ?

Yes.

> and for the recv() blocking function, i should put the buffer character pointer to the second parameter or the packet one?

I can't make head or tail of this, but you should receive into a buffer as large as possible and loop until you have the entire message.

> and for the header, my friend suggested me to add header of 4 bytes to store the packet information, eg. sequence number and size of packet, how can it be implemented!

You don't really need the sequence number, but a message size is a good idea. Just stick it in the front of the message. Unclear what the question is here.

Comment: Correct, except for "it will handle it for me automatically".  You need to check the return value from the `write` or `send` call, and handle partial writes.

Comment: @BenVoigt That statement only applies to the `send()`, and it is correct in blocking mode as per Posix, unless there is an interrupt.

Comment: buf [out]
A pointer to the buffer to receive the incoming data.
len [in]
The length, in bytes, of the buffer pointed to by the buf parameter.

by the MSDN, so for send() case, i put 2000 for len[in] to indicate i want to send 2000 bytes of this buffer char pointer ?

and for the recv() case, I put whatever number for the len[in] parameter ? as it will split the message for me if the length is smaller than 2000 and then wait for next recv() ?

Comment: @Giorgi, Thanks! and i also want to ask, if i dont do the partial writes handling and the send rate in the while loop is very faster (no sleep), so will there be error/lost in server side? for the recv()

Comment: @WesPoon It depends on other factors such as whether you've set the socket blocking or non-blocking and whether you receive any signals.

Comment: by default it should be the blocking function in Windows. ? but i found that it turns to a non-blocking one while execution, troubleshooting...

Answer (score 2):

You will need sendall like [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#sendall), and you will (probably) need to write a similar `receivall`. Here is the `sendall` (slightly modified):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int sendall(int s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
    int bytesleft = *len; // how many we have left to send
    int n = -1;

    while(total < *len) {
        n = send(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n <= 0) {  break; }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total;  

    return (n<=0)?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}
```

And you can read up here how to deal with [message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), which is what you need.

Comment: Why not just return the send-count, or -1? Why the pointer parameter?

Comment: @EJP: I showed OP implementation from that guide, which says send may not send all data it was told to, similar goes with reading I guess.

Comment: @BenVoight It does? I would have expected -1.

Comment: @Giorgi That doesn't  answer my question.

Comment: @EJP: didn't get  you?

Comment: @BenVoigt: is this better?

Comment: @EJP: Well, I usually see `0` from the reading/receiving side, but `0` is also a legal return value from `send`, so it's good to handle it.